# After installing minitest rails, rake test doesn't do anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

The question title pretty much sums it up, but here's a more chronological description:

1. I started a new rails 3.2.9 app, did not pass any special options (ie. did not skip test unit).
2. I added `minitest-rails` to the gemfile and ran bundle install.
3. I deleted the contents of the test folder, and ran `rails g mini_test:install`.

Now if I run `rake test`, nothing happens.

I can make my own rakefile and specify `TestTask` manually, but I don't get the options to do things like `rake test:controllers` that are supposed to come built-in unless I manually dupe all that.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add `require 'test_helper'` on top of your test file. e.g.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should pass" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

The auto generated test_helper file I have looks like that:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

  fixtures :all

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Glad you are making the switch to MiniTest! I may be able to help you get on the right track.

Honestly, I would avoid rake entirely. Try running a test from the command line to make sure your testing suite is working.

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/something.rb
```

After you know your tests are passing then get guard-minitest and set it up to watch your files. When you save a change it will automatically run the test for you. The worst part of minitest and guard is the set up but once you get it going right you'll never want to go back.

https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest

Cheers

Comment: What does the -Itest flag do?

Comment: `-I` (per `man`): "Used to tell Ruby where to load the library scripts.  Directory path will be added to the load-path variable ($:)."  In this case the test directory is being included

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had not run/generate any controller or scaffold command so far.
Once you create a scaffold / controller / model and migrate the database your rake test will start working

Regarding rake test:controllers, when I tried to list out with rake -T it is not still listing

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register minitest-rails as the default testing engine by adding the following to your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :mini_test
end
```

After that, you can run controller tests with the following:

```
rake minitest:controllers
```

Comment: I do have minitest registered as the test framework -- but also I'm not sure why setting it there (in generator settings) would affect the rake task...

Comment: I was missing gem 'minitest-rails' from my :development environment

Comment: "I was missing gem 'minitest-rails' from my :development environment" - this fixed my problem.